# how to print the row of a matrix(multi-dimensional array) in a new line

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, output

I have a multi-dimensional array in C#, I have assigned the indices of the matrices by capturing input from a user, I am trying to implement a conditional structure that will let me print the rows of my matrix each on a separate line, for example if my array is A and A has a dimension of 3 by 3 then the code prints the first three elements on the first line, the next three elements on the next line and so on and so forth. I am trying to achieve this because it will be easier to understand the structure as a normal matrix and also build an entire matrix class with miscallenous operations.

**Code**

```
class Matrix{
 static int[,] matrixA;
 static void Main(string[] args){
   Console.WriteLine("Enter the order of the matrix");
   int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   matrixA = new int[n, n];
  //assigning the matrix with values from the user
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                matrixA[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
   //the code below tries to implement a line break after each row for the matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                
                if( (n-1-i) == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(matrixA[i, j].ToString() + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify my code so that if the array has 9 elements and its a square matrix then each row with three elements are printed on a single line.

Comment: Just like you have a nested for loop to capture input, I would use nested for loops to produce the output.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, I loop through the `i` and check if current row ends there and break?

Comment: Exactly like the input loops... have two loops each going to `n`.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, trying it out now

Comment: @StayOnTarget, am out of ideas, its not working, its printing 4 numbers on the same line. I used `if(n-1-i)==0` to check and print a line break if true

Comment: Maybe edit the question to add what you just tried?

Comment: Code edited in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this for the output:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            
                Console.Write(matrixA[i, j].ToString() + " ");
        }

        Console.Write("\n");
    }
```

When the inner loop is done, that means one row has been completely printed. So that's the only time the newline is needed. (`n` passes of the outer loop ==> `n` newlines printed).

Comment: Yeah it will and thanks, just to be clear why a print statement outside the inner loop?